# Display results grouped by a category

Tags: php, mysql

OK i have no idea how to word the title better but hopefully i can explain better here:

I have a database of animals, with several columns, one of which is named `Category` which contains a single word string such as `frog`, or `newt`.

I can successfully query the database for these things in two separate queries and print the results separately, but i ideally want to use a single query and then split the data afterwards to print the result to the page but in two sections, one for frogs and one for newts.

currently my code looks like this:

```
    $query =    "SELECT * FROM livestock WHERE Category = 'frog' OR Category = 'newt'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));  

    echo"<div class='rowtable'>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $commondraft = $entry['Name'];

        echo"<a href='/stocklist/".$entry['id']."/".commonName($commondraft)."' class='row'>";
        echo"<div class='common'>".$entry['Name']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='descr'>".$row['Description']."</div>";
        echo"<div class='sex'>".$row['Sex']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='age'>".$row['Age']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='size'>".$row['Size']."</div>";  
        echo"<div class='origin'>".$row['Origin']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='scientific'>".$row['Scientific']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='prices'>".$row['Price']."</div>"; 

        echo"</a>";
        }
    echo"</div>";
```

This obviously prints out all entries for both categories of `frog` AND `newt`. How can i select just one category here and then use the other category elsewhere without re-querying the database for just the remaining category?

Comment: Order the data by category in your query, and then implement what’s called a _group break_, by simply comparing the category for each record in your loop with that of the previous one – if they don’t match, that’s your break criterion. At that point, you exit your loop, and output the rest of the records in a second loop.

Comment: (i) Your sort results by category (ii) you loop over results and display them (iii) category is displayed when it changes (i.e. when it is different from previous one)

Comment: _“and output the rest of the records in a second loop”_  … or in the same loop, but after outputting a different header and another `rowtable` DIV or something. (That’s how you would normally implement such a group break, so that it works for multiple categories and not just two.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do what others suggested (`order by Category`), but I think this will be better solution: when you retrieve items from `livestock` table you can put them in separate arrays for every category. I mean, that you can use `$items` array (in my example) as dictionary (hash map) where key is category name and value is array of all items which belongs to that category. Later, when you want to output items from some category just call `output` function with desired category. For example (I have simplified output; you can use this for any amount of categories. You just need to change `$query` in `getItems`):

```
    function getItems($con) {
      $items = array();
      $query =    "SELECT * FROM livestock WHERE Category = 'frog' OR Category = 'newt'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $category = $row['Category'];
         if (!isset($items[$category])) {
            $items[$category] = array();
         }
         array_push($items[$category], $row);
      }
      return $items;
   }

   function output($category, $items) {
      echo"<div class='rowtable'>";
      foreach ($items[$category] as $entry) {
          echo"<div class='common'>".$entry['Name']."</div>"; 
      }
      echo"</div>";
   }

   $items = getItems($con); // $con holds connection to database
   output('frog', $items); // prints just items from frog category
   output('newt', $items); // prints just items from newt category
```